# go getのURL...というトリプルドットはどういう意味ですか？

Tags: go

https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher

上記のthe_platinum_searcherのREADMEを見ると、インストール方法として下記のように記載されていました。

```
$ go get -u github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher/...
```

`...`を省くとbinにptがインストールされませんでした。この`...`はどういった役割なのでしょうか？

Comment: `go help packages` を実行すると、`An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns.` と説明されています。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ワイルドカードの事ではないでしょうか。

[go - The Go Programming Language > Goコマンドでのパッケージリストについて](http://golang-jp.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Go__________________)

> 多くのコマンドが以下のように一連のパッケージに適用できます。
>
> ```
> go action [packages]
> ```
>
> 通常、[packages]はインポートパスのリストです。
>   （中略）
>   インポートパスが1つ以上の"..."ワイルドカード（それぞれが空文字・スラッシュを伴う文字列を含む任意の文字列にマッチする）を含む場合、それらのパターンにマッチする名前を含むGOPATHツリーに存在するすべてのパッケージディレクトリに展開されます。

Answer (score 0):

カレントディレクトリ以下を再帰的に見に行きます